# How to prevent "translation missing" error using Devise with custom registrations controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I've tried everything but keep getting "translation missing" text in my flash error on sign up using Devise.

Here is some context:

- I am using Devise for authentication.
- Instead of "User", I created a "Customer" model.
- I wanted to add some attributes to the Customer model, so I customized the Devise Registrations controller. I have specified that in Routes.
- One of the attributes (invite_url_param) has validation in the Customer model for presence and uniqueness.

Here's the exact error text I'm getting in the flash message:

```
translation missing: en.devise.registrations.customer.Invite url param That email has already been used - please try again
```

I want instead for the error to read: "That email has already been used - please try again" - so without the translation missing part.

But I can't figure out how to get rid of the "translation missing: en.devise.registrations.customer.Invite url param".

It's not specific to the invite_url_param either, if I try to create a customer with a password that's too short, I get this error text:

```
translation missing: en.devise.registrations.customer.Password Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
```

Here's my Registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
  prepend_before_action :authenticate_scope!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  prepend_before_action :set_minimum_password_length, only: [:new, :edit]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource({})
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.invite_url_param = resource.email.split("@").first.tr(".", "")

    if resource.referred_by
      unless Invite.find_by_receiver_email(resource.email)
        if Customer.find_by_invite_url_param(resource.referred_by)
          @invite = Invite.new(receiver_email: resource.email)
          @invite.customer = Customer.find_by_invite_url_param(resource.referred_by)
          @invite.save
        end
      end
    end

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      unless SaverGuest.find_by_email(resource.email)
        CustomerMailer.signup_bill(resource).deliver
      end
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      resource.errors.full_messages.each {|x| set_flash_message :error, x}
      redirect_to after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    # render :edit
  end

  # PUT /resource
  # We need to use a copy of the resource because we don't want to change
  # the current user in place.
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      bypass_sign_in resource, scope: resource_name
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      # clean_up_passwords resource
      # set_minimum_password_length
      flash[:error] = "That link is already taken"
      redirect_to invite_path
    end
  end

  # DELETE /resource
  def destroy
    resource.destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message! :notice, :destroyed
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
  end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  def cancel
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    redirect_to new_registration_path(resource_name)
  end

  protected

  def update_needs_confirmation?(resource, previous)
    resource.respond_to?(:pending_reconfirmation?) &&
      resource.pending_reconfirmation? &&
      previous != resource.unconfirmed_email
  end

  # By default we want to require a password checks on update.
  # You can overwrite this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end

  # Build a devise resource passing in the session. Useful to move
  # temporary session data to the newly created user.
  def build_resource(hash=nil)
    self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
  end

  # Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
  # RegistrationsController.
  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  end

  # The path used after sign up. You need to overwrite this method
  # in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(:customer) || root_path
  end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts. You need to overwrite
  # this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource)
    router_name = Devise.mappings[scope].router_name
    context = router_name ? send(router_name) : self
    context.respond_to?(:root_path) ? context.root_path : "/"
  end

  # The default url to be used after updating a resource. You need to overwrite
  # this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(:customer) || root_path
  end

  # Authenticates the current scope and gets the current resource from the session.
  def authenticate_scope!
    send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!", force: true)
    self.resource = send(:"current_#{resource_name}")
  end

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :email, :password, :referred_by)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:invite_url_param)
  end

  def translation_scope
    'devise.registrations'
  end
end
```

Here's my Customer model:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_many :invites

   validates :invite_url_param, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Here's my config/locales/devise.en.yml file:

```
# Additional translations at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n

en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Your email address has been successfully confirmed."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions for how to confirm your email address in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive an email with instructions for how to confirm your email address in a few minutes."
    failure:
      already_authenticated: "You are already signed in."
      inactive: "Your account is not activated yet."
      invalid: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
      locked: "Your account is locked."
      last_attempt: "You have one more attempt before your account is locked."
      not_found_in_database: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
      timeout: "Your session expired. Please sign in again to continue."
      unauthenticated: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
      unconfirmed: "You have to confirm your email address before continuing."
    mailer:
      confirmation_instructions:
        subject: "Confirmation instructions"
      reset_password_instructions:
        subject: "Reset password instructions"
      unlock_instructions:
        subject: "Unlock instructions"
      password_change:
        subject: "Password Changed"
    omniauth_callbacks:
      failure: "Could not authenticate you from %{kind} because \"%{reason}\"."
      success: "Successfully authenticated from %{kind} account."
    passwords:
      no_token: "You can't access this page without coming from a password reset email. If you do come from a password reset email, please make sure you used the full URL provided."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions on how to reset your password in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive a password recovery link at your email address in a few minutes."
      updated: "Your password has been changed successfully. You are now signed in."
      updated_not_active: "Your password has been changed successfully."
    registrations:
      destroyed: "Bye! Your account has been successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon."
      signed_up: ""
      signed_up_but_inactive: "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is not yet activated."
      signed_up_but_locked: "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is locked."
      signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please follow the link to activate your account."
      update_needs_confirmation: "You updated your account successfully, but we need to verify your new email address. Please check your email and follow the confirm link to confirm your new email address."
      updated: ""
      customer:
        invite_url_param:
          taken: ""
          blank: ""
    sessions:
      signed_in: ""
      signed_out: ""
      already_signed_out: "Signed out successfully."
    unlocks:
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions for how to unlock your account in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your account exists, you will receive an email with instructions for how to unlock it in a few minutes."
      unlocked: "Your account has been unlocked successfully. Please sign in to continue."
  errors:
    messages:
      already_confirmed: "was already confirmed, please try signing in"
      confirmation_period_expired: "needs to be confirmed within %{period}, please request a new one"
      expired: "has expired, please request a new one"
      not_found: "not found"
      not_locked: "was not locked"
      not_saved:
        one: "1 error prohibited this %{resource} from being saved:"
        other: "%{count} errors prohibited this %{resource} from being saved:"
      taken: "Please try again"
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        customer:
          attributes:
            password:
              too_short: "Password is too short (minimum is %{count} characters)"
            email:
              taken: "That email has already been used - please try again."
            invite_url_param:
              taken: "That email has already been used - please try again."
              blank: "can't really happen"
```

And here's my config/locales/en.yml file where I think the end of that error text is getting picked up:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        customer:
          attributes:
            password:
              too_short: "Password is too short (minimum is %{count} characters)"
            email:
              taken: "That email has already been used - please try again."
            invite_url_param:
              taken: "That email has already been used - please try again."
              blank: "can't really happen"
```

Comment: It looks like you have the same locales in 2 files. Have you tried only having them in one?

Comment: I had tried having them only in one with the same result. Thanks for commenting though; it ended up that the below answer + correcting my error message handling in registrations controller was the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are definately going to get that error, look at the locale paths it gives in the errors:

```
en.devise.registrations.customer.Invite
```

and

```
en.devise.registrations.customer.Password
```

Now follow your locale indent paths down, and you have no Password or Invite definition inside of the en.devise.registrations.customer:

```
en:
  devise:
    registrations:
      customer:
        uh oh! no pasword!
```

So it has no locale to provide. So your solutions are as follows:

1. Make a locale at that path
2. Make Devise use a different locale for displaying the error message.

for further reading and to get more to grips with how I18n works: [Take a look at the official rails api](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) and [the I18n section of the devise gem repo readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#i18n).

Comment: Thanks, John - that was a major part of my eventual fix. Adding a string at that locale and then also my passing of the error was incorrect - it should be resource.errors.messages.keys.each {|x| set_flash_message :error, x} instead of resource.errors.full_messages.each {|x| set_flash_message :error, x} - thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Final code in case it helps folks who have a similar issue:

Fixed create method in the registrations controller to get the message key of the errors:

```
def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.invite_url_param = resource.email.split("@").first.tr(".", "")

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.referred_by
        unless Invite.find_by_receiver_email(resource.email)
          if Customer.find_by_invite_url_param(resource.referred_by)
            @invite = Invite.new(receiver_email: resource.email)
            @invite.customer = Customer.find_by_invite_url_param(resource.referred_by)
            @invite.save
          end
        end
      end
      unless SaverGuest.find_by_email(resource.email)
        CustomerMailer.signup_bill(resource).deliver
      end
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      resource.errors.messages.keys.each {|x| set_flash_message :error, x}
      redirect_to after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  end
```

with `resource.errors.messages.keys.each {|x| set_flash_message :error, x}` being the key part.

And then, as John suggested, I needed to have strings at the correct nested locale in the config/locales/devise.en.yml file like so:

```
en:
  devise:
    registrations:
      customer:
        invite_url_param: "That email has already been used - please try again."
        email: "That email has already been used - please try again."
        password: "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"
```